# If I upgrade my Draw Something, who gets to use the bonus words?

Tags: draw-something

I've noticed a few ads in between drawing sessions that recommend I purchase the game (instead of using the free version).  It mentions 1000 more words, no ads, free stuff, etc, but who gets to draw the 1000 + words?  Is it the buyer who gets to draw them and any user ( including those who haven't purchased the game) can guess those new words?

Do I have to face an opponent that has purchased Draw Something to be able to use words found within that 1000+ word bonus? 
[image]

Comment: They're giving free stuff with the paid-for version? How big of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paid users of DrawSomething have the 1000+ words bonus. It means that when the server gives them the choice of three words, it extracts them from a bigger pool of available words.

You will not have any problems playing with "free" users, the only drawback is that when it comes her/his turn to draw, words are taken from the limited words pool.

Comment: Can you source this?  This is what I assumed, but looking for source or testing reference.

Comment: I searched a lot but unfortunately I have no web source to point out, only my personal experience playing with a user that has the "paid" version. Feel free to leave the question open until you get some written official reference.

Comment: I guess its been hard to tell, as they are adding words to both lists constantly - from what I've noticed.

Comment: I'm willing to backup @Drake's answer based on my experience (some 500 turns). I'm able to tell which of my friends have the paid version based solely on the words they send. Words I've *never* seen from my free version.